# CSS stack a right side of a row to under the left one when making the web smaller

Tags: html, css

I need the container #3, to shrink or to move underneath #2. I don't know how to do this, I might need to do flex but don't know. I need the left one(#2) to stay the same size and the right one (#3) to be the one that moves around. I don't know what more to add or change, I've tried with infinite combinations and have not done it correctly.

I want it like this:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL2cf.png)
and when having the nav smaller like this :   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGKMr.png)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#general {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4f6d7a;
}

div#enlaces {
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #166088;
}

div#tablas_carpetas {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1400px;
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
}

div#tablas {
  order: 1;
  background-color: #dfc0c0;
  height: 600px;
  width: 40%;
}

div#carpetas {
  order: 2;
  width: 60%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
}

@media all and (max-width: 450px) {
  div#tablas_carpetas {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  div#tablas {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  div#carpetas {
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="general">
  <div id="enlaces">1</div>
  <div id="tablas_carpetas">
    <div id="tablas">2</div>
    <div id="carpetas">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="anuncios">4</div>
  <div id="pie">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working just fine or as you want!!

Comment: hi, I need the panel number 3 (as in the answer from underneath) to be the only one to move and shrink, or eaven go under panel nº2. Its now working as I whant.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a display grid instead of flex on it when your reach the media query you want like below. Let me know If this is what you want.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#general {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4f6d7a;
}

div#enlaces {
  float: center;
  display: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #166088;
}

div#tablas_carpetas {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1400px;
  background-color: #DBE9EE;
  
}

div#tablas {
  order: 1;
  background-color: #dfc0c0;
  height: 600px;
  width: 40%;
}

div#carpetas {
  order: 2;
  width: 60%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
}

@media all and (max-width: 450px) {
  div#tablas_carpetas {
    display:grid;
  }
  div#tablas {
    width: 40%;
    order: 1;
  }
  div#carpetas {
    max-width: 60%;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="general">
  <div id="enlaces">1</div>
  <div id="tablas_carpetas">
    <div id="tablas">2</div>
    <div id="carpetas">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="anuncios">4</div>
  <div id="pie">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, sorry I have not explained my self well ... I whant the div#tablas to stay the same size, and div#carpetas to be the one to shrink when making the web broser smaller, or to move down if its too small like a samartphone. how can I do this?

Comment: Ok let me sit this for you and see if that's what you want.

Comment: I edited the code see if that's what you want. let me know

Comment: hi,sorry, I still see the pink part mooving (I need it to fit straight), and the green one still uses 50% of the width of the page when making the navigator small-shrink as a mobile phone (instead of going under de pink one), can it be that there is nothing inside the containers or that doesnt matter? I need the pink container to  be fix.

Comment: @JaviNitro5 look at above code. so you can grid the divs at mobile and then if you want it to stay 40% and 60% just put the width of that. personally i would do 100% on both on tablas and carpetas on mobile unless you have some sort of plan on the space.